# In asp.net is there anyway to view whats in httpcontext.Cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I see what's in my HttpContext.Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033081/how-can-i-see-whats-in-my-httpcontext-cache)

Something funny is happening where things I think are getting cached don't appear to be and expiration doesn't seem to be working as I expect.  Is there any admin tool or code sample to view to current cache on the server.  I know things like Redis has the ability to do this but not sure with the regular asp.net cache.

- All things stored in the cache
- When they were added
- When they are expiring
- How much space they are taking up (memory)

on an asp.net-MVC site?

Comment: you're referring to asp.net output caching, right?  (as opposed to caching on the client) - if so, see this related SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343462/how-can-i-view-the-contents-of-the-asp-net-outputcache

Comment: Point 1 is simple, by enumerating over the Cache object. Points 2 and 3 are, unfortunately, not exposed by the `System.Web.Caching.Cache` object. Point 4 is possible, but difficult. A search will reveal there are many - but no easy and reliable/accurate - ways to measure object size in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like that [there is answer on your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033081/how-can-i-see-whats-in-my-httpcontext-cache) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343462/how-can-i-view-the-contents-of-the-asp-net-outputcache) or you can check [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4170/Exploring-ASP-NET-Session-State-and-Cache-data)